# What would be a good neural net model for pick 3 lotteries?

Tags: neural-network

This is just for fun to see if neural network predictions increase my odds of getting pick 3 lotteries correct.

Right now i just have a simple model of 30 input units, 30 hidden units, and 30 output units.

30 because if the pick 3 result was something like 124, i would make so that all my inputs are 0's except input[1] = 1 (because i assign 0 to 9 for the first digit), input[12] = 1 (because i assign 10 to 19 for the middle digit), input[24] = 1 (because i assign 20 to 29 for the last digit). I just do that so that my inputs are able store placement of digits.
i am training it so that if enter inputs for one draw, it gives me outputs for the next draw.

Do you know of a better model (if you have had experience with neural networks that dealt with pick3 lotteries)?